# What does "alternate life paths so close to them" mean?

Tags: everything-everywhere-all-at-once

Waymond motivates Evelyn:

> Waymond: Every failure here branched off into a success for another Evelyn
> in another life. Most people only have a few significant
> **alternate life paths so close to them**. But you, here,
> you're capable of anything because you're so bad at everything.

What does "alternate life paths so close to them" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it means "Most people have one or two things they are very good at, so chance variations in life circumstances don't make much of a difference - a great doctor in this world might be a nurse or a medical researcher in another world but that's not much of a difference. You on the other hand, have no standout skill, so the variations are much wider, since chance and hard work could make you into a singer, a fighter, a doctor, or almost anything at all"

Comment: Prefigured by the first tax audit scene

Comment: I think it's a little more than that, hence why failure was important.  I don't think it's just that a person with less affinity to a particular profession or lifestyle has more options.  I think it's more that every decision produces branches of possibility, and when you try and fail a lot that makes a lot of branches.  If you dreamed of being an author and failed, then there is some set of circumstances that would have led to you succeeding, and so there is a universe where you are a successful author.  Evelyn has failed at so many dreams that there is a her doing just about everything.